# "Fonts and encoding" settings in Chrome not working unless I edit custom.css

Tags: google-chrome, fonts

I am using RedHad Enterprise 6 and Chrome 19.0.1084.46.

I noticed that font rendering was better in Firefox, so I tried to customize the fonts in the Settings dialog. Unfortunately, no matter what I do in the "Fonts and encoding" section, Chrome ignores such changes... unless I add the following line to ~/.config/rhel6/google-chrome/Default/User StyleSheets/Custom.css:

> *{font-family:FreeSans!important}

When I save the file Chrome instantaneously picks up the change and renders everything using the font specified in the "Standard" option. However, the problem is that *everything* is rendered using this font, even monospace blocks. In other words, it is like the Standard font completely overrides the other ones (Serif, Sans-serif, Fixed-width). Note: strangely, the font rendering example appearing to the right of the font selection drop-down list fails too (it is rendered using the standard font).

What I would like is to be able to customize each font family separately.